# How to insert 2 images and 1 text box on the same row div

Tags: html, css, web-applications, formatting, frontend

I have in mind to display something like this in my web app:
[image: objective display]

At the moment my horizontal image isn't at the same level as the vertical one so a big white space appear between the text box and the horizontal image.

My code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <p class="paragrafos">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla. Vulputate enim nulla aliquet.
        </p> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5"> <img id="img_1" src="app/1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5"> <img id="img_2" src="app/2.jpeg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried something with css ?

Comment: @godfather just things like the size of the image. I thought that margin-* will solve the problem but it doesn't

Comment: yesterday when you posted this i did a close attempt with css positions but i dont know if it helps you

Comment: if you can post your css it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the horizontal image on the same level as the text should do it. You mentioned that you did not do that. Is there a reason? Can you change the HTML?

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <p class="paragrafos">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla. Vulputate enim nulla aliquet.
        </p> 
        <img id="img_1" src="app/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5"> <img id="img_2" src="app/2.jpeg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick! I'm just gonna change some margins and image's size. Thanks a lot! I did not do it because I didn't thought about it!

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="row "  >
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <p class="paragrafos">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla. Vulputate enim nulla aliquet.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5"> <img id="img_1" src="app/1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5"> <img id="img_2" src="app/2.jpeg"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but that's not what I want.